# Locative prepositions

Tags: locatives

Please help. My kid's homework makes me cry)))
The task is to choose a completely INCORRECT sentence:

1. The book is on the table (sure it's 100% correct)
2. The book is in the table (I think it's correct if the book is on an inner shelf of the table or is locked in a drawer of the table)
3. The book is on top of the table (sure it's better to say just ON, but I think ON TOP OF is also possible to be used here)
4. The book is under the table (100% correct)
   Am I right and are all the four sentences correct? If I am wrong, please let me know which one is incorrect.

Comment: You're quite right; all of them are completely grammatical. However, look at how hard you had to work to come up with a context for no. 2 -- none of the other ones were that hard (and _on top of_ is just as good as _on_). Grammaticality is often a matter of how likely it is that a reasonable context for the intended meaning actually exists. If it doesn't, then grammaticality is at least moot.

Comment: Boy, what a bad question (the homework, not yours).

Comment: Erm, you can't learn anything about grammar from the question here - but you can learn something about tests and exams. As John L said above, you had to work quite hard to find a  good context for the second sentence. A lot of language tests are like that. They want you to choose the right answer for what they consider to be likely situations. The Golden Rule for language exams of any sort - in fact maybe for any exam -  is "***Give the monkey what they want***". This, in short, means: learn to understand what the examiner wants, as opposed to what is true or right. Here, ...

Comment: ... *you* are right and the test is wrong. Sentence 2 is both grammatical and potentially meaningful. However, it is unlikely to be what the examiner wants. It is not a banana. Give the monkey what they want  (because you want the monkey's marks - it doesn't matter who is right!). "I was right but I failed the exam" is probably not the result that anyone wants.

Comment: @Araucaria Help! I've got a monkey who doesn't want to be referred to with *they*. He looks kinda pissed off, and no, I don't know what sex.

Comment: @deadrat My advice: *hide!* (Or club them unconscious with a CamGEL).

Comment: @deadrat I always feel that way about Flump. They look like an agressive angry male pink/orange gorilla, and yet they have a kind of pouty, lipsticky, very womany look. So it's difficult to tell ...

Comment: @deadrat It's a bit difficult to be angry with someone who looks like your grandma wearing too much lipstick. (But it still has to be done obviously)

Comment: @deadrat if you don't know what sex, on what basis are you referring to said monkey  as "he"?

Comment: @verbose It's the deprecated third person masculine singular indeterminate.

Comment: @deadrat  No, no, *he's* the deprecated third person masculine singular indeterminate. It's the third person neuter. 

Comment: @verbose Oh, dear. An emoji. I'm too old for those. Weren't you objecting to my using *he* to refer to a monkey, the sex of which was unknown to me?

Comment: @deadrat I was trying to be funny. You said *It's the deprecated third person masculine singular indeterminate*. I decided to interpret that *It's* as ***It** is*, and counter with *No, **it** isn't, **he** is*. I guess it's [crickets](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117202/when-you-tell-a-joke-and-nobody-laughs/117210#117210)

Comment: @verbose I'm sorry that I made you explain your witticism, thus draining the amusement from it. My fault for not getting the word play. I blame the drugs for making me too literal minded.

Comment: @deadrat You say "drugs" and "literal minded" like those are bad things.

Comment: @verbose We are amused. But good point about the drugs. I just meant to provide an explanation. But literal mindedness is the curse that the ignorant place on the rest of us. I hate it when I become one of those persons I complain about.

Answer (score 3):

On a multiple-choice exam, the instruction "choose the 100% completely INCORRECT sentence" means nothing of the kind—unless (depending on how sneaky the exam giver is) one of the answers is "None of the above." Rather, the instruction means "choose the sentence that is more wrong than the others" (if most of the options are at least a little bit wrong) or "choose the sentence that is closest to being wrong (if most of the options are more or less correct). Any other way of reading the question is an exercise in self-defeating self-gratification ("I'm right and the test is wrong, and I've got the F to prove it!"). I speak as one who has endured many self-inflicted wounds out of vanity.

As both John Lawler and Araucaria indicate in comments above, the answer to the question "Which of the sentences is closer to being wrong than the others?" is obvious—and the poster achknowledges that obviousness by easily identifying places to put a book **on**, **on top of**, or **under** a generic table that may or may not have any features besides one or more vertical supports and a flat horizontal surface—but finding it necessary to specify a table with either an inner shelf or a drawer in order to put the book **in** it.

Even then, idiomatically, it is highly unusual for a fluent English speaker to answer a question such as "Where's the tape?" with "It's in the table." Far more common is the reply, "It's in the table drawer" or "it's in the shelf of the table." A Google Books search for "[in the table](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20table%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" returns very few matches for *table* as "piece of furniture capable of holding a book"; the vast majority of the matches are for *table* in the sense of "chart of tabulated data."

Which option is closest to being 100% completely INCORRECT? The one you have to add shelves and drawers to.

---

**Update (1/24/17):** Just in case the comments below disappear at some point, I want to include the OP's startling punchline, which appeared following all of my pontificating (above):

> **It's incredible, but the correct answer was "ON TOP OF". So, according to this test, it is possible to say ON THE TABLE, IN THE TABLE and UNDER THE TABLE, and it is incorrect to say ON TOP OF THE TABLE. Crazy people, poor kids.**

There's a lesson here for me (and perhaps for other question answerers at this site) about the hazards of thinking that I've got everything figured out.

Comment: It's incredible, but the correct answer was "ON TOP OF".  So, according to this test, it is possible to say ON THE TABLE, IN THE TABLE and UNDER THE TABLE, and it is incorrect to say ON TOP OF THE TABLE. Crazy people, poor kids.

Comment: I am humbled and dismayed. Thank you, Alena Ioffe, for that lesson in why I should never assume I know anything about how other people (including test preparers) think.

Comment: The idiot is behind the test.